# Why are my ORC with SNAPPY compressed files larger than the original files?

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, gzip, snappy, orc

I set up a first Hive table with GZIP-compressed files:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_gzip (
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED,
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION
  's3://bucket/files_gzip/';
```

Then I set up another Hive table with ORC format:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_orc (
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
)
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION
   's3://bucket/files_orc/';
ALTER TABLE table_orc SET tblproperties ("orc.compress" ="SNAPPY");
```

And then I uncompressed and recompressed from GZIP to ORC using this query:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_gzip SELECT * FROM table_orc
```

Once this query finished, I had new ORC-compressed files in 's3://bucket/files_orc/'. So far so good.

However when I looked at the files, **they went from 500 1.2GiB files to 500 1.6GiB files**.

What did I do wrong? Why are my ORC-SNAPPY compressed files larger than the original files? Is GZIP a better compression method?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: First, GZip is **indeed** designed for deep compression, but requires a lot of CPU; whereas Snappy is designed for minimal CPU overhead, that's why it's perfect for intermediate results (e.g. data produced by a Mapper to be consumed by a Reducer). **Why don't you just use Wikipedia??** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snappy_(compression)

Comment: Then, `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_gzip SELECT * FROM table_orc` does not read from `table_gzip` to feed `table_orc`. It's the other way around.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter it isn't clear what the value of Snappy is if it in fact makes the overall file size on disk larger. Are Snappy-compressed files faster to process as intermediate results (e.g. in the mapper to reducer situation you described)?

Comment: @maxcountryman >> give some context. How are you using Snappy compression - on top of CSV files, inside a Parquet or ORC structure, something else? Then _"file size larger"_ -- larger than what, uncompressed files, GZip files, something else?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Snappy with Parquet. Larger than uncompressed.

Comment: @maxcountryman >> it's true that content with absolutely no pattern (e.g. random numbers in binary format, or encrypted stuff) will resist any kind of compression - Snappy, GZip, whatever; maybe you're in that case?  By the way, do you apply some ordering (which would enforce some local patterns) before serializing to Parquet?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I would be very surprised if that's the case: many columns are just enumerations and repeated many times over so even the most basic compression should be effective. However in practice, the Snappy encoded Parquet is ~20% larger than the uncompressed Parquet. (One note, it's currently very small data, under a megabyte, but expected to be gigabytes later.)

Comment: Right, enums will be "compacted" via tokenization anyway; adding compression on top will not make much difference except adding metadata.

Comment: Parquet **is** complex...